# Running periodic queries on google cloud sql instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud postgre instance and I'd like to run periodic sql queries on it and use the monitoring system to alert the user with the results.
How can I accomplish just using the gcp platform? Without having to develop a separate app.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of, There is no Built-in feature for recurring queries in `Cloud SQL` at the moment.

So you have to implement your own. You can Use `Cloud Scheduler` to trigger a `Cloud function` (via HTTP/S endpoint) that runs the query on `Cloud SQL` and then notify the user in the way that suits your needs (I would recommend using `pub/sub`).

and you might want to save the result in a GCS bucket and the user is to pull the result from there.

---

Also, you might want to check `BigQuery`. It has a built-in feature of [Scheduling queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).